# WebSharper F# - How to run a template project created with VS Code and Ionide?

Tags: f#, mono, visual-studio-code, websharper, ionide

I have never worked with .NET before and I would like to know how to run a WebSharper F# project without any IDE.

### Context

- I'm running Linux with Mono 4.4.2
- The project was created with VS Code and Ionide, using the template **websharperserverclient**
- I'm able to compile the code using the automatically generated file `build.sh` or by executing `xbuild`, but only `.dll` files are generated, I couldn't see any `.exe`

I thank in advance for any help!

#### Updates

Using **websharperserverclient** I get weird results like the one showed in the picture below and `xsp4` doesn't give any hint about it.

[image]

Comment: I don't have **dotnet** in my environment, only **mono**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSharper can run as an ASP.NET module, so the easiest way to start your app is to run `xsp4` (mono's self-hosted ASP.NET server) in the project folder. That's good as a quick server for testing; for production you should rather configure a server like [Apache](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/) or [nginx](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/).

Another solution would be to use the **websharpersuave** template instead, which does generate a self-serving executable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried `xsp4`, but I got only 404 errors. I'll try **websharpersuave**, but I would really like to understand what is wrong with that template.

Comment: Although I needed to fix manually some paths on `.fsproj` file, I was able to run a server with the template **websharpersuave**.

Comment: **websharpersuave** is working, but this [issue](https://github.com/intellifactory/websharper.suave/issues/9) really bothers me. Do you have another suggestion @Tarmil?

Comment: I have created [this repository](https://github.com/boechat107/websharper_samples) with a working example.

Comment: I am still figuring out the issue with the current serverclient template, but in the meantime you can check my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190505/f-ionide-websharperserverclient-how-to-run/40203087#40203087) to switch from OWIN to HttpModule, which works with xsp.