# F# ionide websharperserverclient - how to run

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, websharper, ionide, websharper.ui.next

I have a problem with running  `websharperserverclient` template app from ionide project generator, and cannot find any information on the web how to do it - the closest thing i got was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559325/websharper-f-how-to-run-a-template-project-created-with-vs-code-and-ionide) - I actually tried to run it with `xsp4` in the project folder (where the `Web.config` file is) but every time got a 404 (screenshot attached: [xsp4 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5gt8.png)). Of course before starting xsp i run the `./build.sh` (or `FAKE build`) script and it finishes with no errors. I had no problems with `websharpersuave` and `websharperspa` project templates (the second one runs with `xsp4` and works like a charm).

**EDIT**

The error message in text form:

> **System.Web.HttpException** 
>   The resource cannot be found.
>
> **Description:** HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> **Details:** Requested URL: /
>
> **Exception stack trace:**
>
> ```
> at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) <0x4202aa80 + 0x00733> in <filename unknown>:0
>   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) <0x4202a400 + 0x00153> in <filename unknown>:0
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () <0x42012000 + 0x04416> in <filename unknown>:0
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () <0x42010800 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0
> ```

Comment: If you could copy the error from your screenshot and include it in the question as text, that would be helpful. Screenshots can't be Googled by someone else later on who might get the same error. BTW, I don't know WebSharper at all, so I'm afraid I won't be much help with your actual problem. But including the error message in your question (as text, not a picture) will probably help whoever *can* answer your question to give you better answers.

Comment: @rmunn added the error in text form - thanks for the advice

Comment: You're welcome. I improved your formatting, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there seem to be issues with running the OWIN module with xsp, which I'm investigating. In the meantime, you can switch to using WebSharper's HttpModules by doing the following:

- Uncomment the nodes that are indicated as pertaining to the HttpModule in `Web.config` (namely, the nodes `system.web/httpModules` and `system.webServer/modules`).
- Remove the NuGet dependencies on `WebSharper.Owin` and `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` (and make sure that the corresponding dlls are deleted from your `bin` folder).
- Remove or comment out `Startup.fs`.